# Why is my Cordova outdated in PhoneGap Build?

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have made an app with PhoneGap and did so just a few seconds ago by doing the

> npm install -g phonegap

then I checked the verison by doing:

> phonegap -v

it returned:

> 0.9.4

How do I update that? I just followed their sample on the internet. When I go to upload to https://build.phonegap.com/apps/ it gives me this error:

> This app is using PhoneGap 2.2.0. We are ending support for Cordova versions below 2.5 -- please upgrade. This app isn't using the latest version of PhoneGap. We recommend upgrading to 3.7.0.

my cordova's version is 5.1.1?

```
c:\users\user>cordova -v
5.1.1
c:\users\user>phonegap -v
0.9.4
```

How do I update from PhoneGap 2.2.0 to 2.5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but I had same issue.
I've solved a few minutes ago with version of last release:

```
npm install -g phonegap@5.1.1-0.29.0
```

Regards